# a elementary number theory problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

please help me to find $ a,b \in \Bbb Z $ such that $a|b$ and  $ \forall z \in \Bbb Z $,we have $a+z|b+z$.

Comment: How about $a=b$?

Comment: This statement couldn't be true for all $z \in \mathbb{Z}$. See $z=-a$. So it must be for all $z \neq -a$. Though this may not be helpful lol

Comment: @Clayton it's seem only answer of this problem is $a=b$ but how prove that don't exist $a,b$ that is true in this condition.

Comment: @Wishingwell But taken literally this gives a trivial proof that $a=b$: it's *true* that $0 \mid 0$ (so $z=-a$ is possible) but $0 \nmid n$ for any non-zero $n$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $a = b$ the result is trivial.
So I will assume that $a \ne b$.

If $a$ and $b$ are positive,
we must have $a < b$.
If we choose $z$ such that
$2(a+z) > (b+z)$
(i.e., $z > b-2a$),
then $1 < \frac{b+z}{a+z} < 2$
which contradicts $(a+z)|(b+z)$.
So $a$ and $b$ cannot both be positive.

If $a$ and $b$ are both negative,
by looking at negative $z$
we come to the same conclusion.

So one of them must be positive and
the other negative.
Assume $a < 0$, and let
$c = -a$. Then
$(z-c)|(z+b)$ and $b$ and $c$ are positive integers.
Again by choosing $z$ large enough,
so $z > c$ and $z+b < 2(z-c)$
(or $z > b+2c$),
we get $1 < \frac{z+b}{z-c} < 2$,
a contradiction.

Therefore the only solution is $a = b$.

Note that this works if $a, b$, and $z$
are restricted to the positive integers.
In this case, we cannot set $z = 0$
to get $a|b$.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say $b=\lambda a$. Then for $z=b$ we get $\lambda+1\mid 2\lambda \Rightarrow \lambda=1$ (since $\gcd(\lambda,\lambda+1)=1$).

Comment: This will not work if $a,b, z \in \Bbb N$, because we cannot set $z=0$ to conclude $a|b$.

Comment: @martycohen: I don't understand. We know from the hypothesis that $a\mid b$. Is there a problem in my solution? I believe it works for $a,b,z\in\mathbb N$.